# proc_open is disabled. But not in php.ini

Tags: php, windows, function

Hello i am trying to use php's proc_open() function on my personal Windows server, but i am getting error like, php warning : proc_open is disabled  for security reasons.

But in php.ini i have commented disable_functions and removed anything like blocking these functions. Still getting these errors.

What could be wrong?

I am using ZPanel and Windows 2008.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lied in Zpanel's httpd-vhosts.conf file, actually i have a Windows 2008 Server with ZPanel and suhosin installed, so in httpd-vhosts.conf file there was php suhosin.func.blackblist = proc_open,
so i commented this line, and restarted APACHE from services, Now its working flawlessly fine.

Thanks everyone for taking time to read and answer!